# Combine and update table in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

table test:

```
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| source | target | count | prob |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| test1  | test2  |     2 |    1 |
| cat    | dog    |     2 |    1 |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
```

table test2:

```
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| source | target | count | prob |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| cat    | dog    |     1 |  0.5 |
| dog    | cat    |     1 |  0.5 |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
```

I tried to combine two table by code blew

```
select test.count+test2.count, test.prob+test.prob 
from test, test2
where (test.source = test2.source) and (test.target = test2.target);
```

if i want update test table like this

```
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| source | target | count | prob |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| test1  | test2  |     2 |    1 |
| cat    | dog    |     3 |   1.5|
| dog    | cat    |     1 |   0.5|
+--------+--------+-------+------+
```

Is any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Union with group by .

```
select source , target , SUM(`count`), SUM(prob )
(select * from test
Union 
select * from test2) as t
group by source,target
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are inserting and updating the duplicate entry why not use `composite key` and use `insert into select from` and `on duplicate key update`

Consider the following

```
create table table1(
  source varchar(100),
  target varchar(100), 
  `count` int, 
  prob int, 
  primary key(source,target)
);
```

Note that here the primary key is `(source,target)`

```
create table table2(
   source varchar(100),
   target varchar(100), 
   `count` int, 
   prob int
 );
```

Lets put some data and it becomes

```
mysql> select * from table1 ;
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| source | target | count | prob |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| cat    | dog    |     2 |    1 |
| test1  | test2  |     2 |    1 |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from table2 ;
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| source | target | count | prob |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| test1  | test2  |     2 |    1 |
| cat    | dog    |     3 |    2 |
| dog    | cat    |     1 |    1 |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now lets write the query

```
insert into table1
select * from
(
 select * from table2
)x
on duplicate key update 
table1.`count` = x.`count` +table1.`count` , 
table1.prob =table1.prob+x.prob ;
```

After running the above query the `table1` data becomes

```
mysql> select * from table1 ;
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| source | target | count | prob |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
| cat    | dog    |     5 |    3 |
| dog    | cat    |     1 |    1 |
| test1  | test2  |     4 |    2 |
+--------+--------+-------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: this solution just could be used in this case,not the example...,that 's wierd ....